# Kappa and Accuracy

Tags: r, statistics, svm

so my question is more related to statistic. I trained a classifier with SVM using R, however, I got very strange result which does not make sense for me where Kappa is very high and accuracy is very low as follows:

```
C     Accuracy   Kappa     
0.25  0.1850838  0.09200168
0.50  0.1900418  0.08910718
1.00  0.2048670  0.08894189
```

what does that mean?

Comment: Statistics questions should go to stats.stackexchange

Comment: Questions about model interpretation are not specific programming questions and therefore do not belong on Stack Overflow. If you have questions about interpreting models, you should be asking at [stats.se] or [datascience.se].